# Count orders by days of the week, adding Saturday & Sunday counts to Friday

Tags: t-sql, date

I would like to get the count of ordered items from monday to sunday but adding saturday and sunday orders to fridays, so the query results would only display Orderdates (Monday to Friday)

I have this sql already that shows orders for every single day  of the week:

```
select DATENAME(weekday,orderdate) Day,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), orderdate, 103) orderdate, 
COUNT(orderdate) Orders  
from Orders_tb
where orderDate >= '2012-03-01 00:00:00.000'  
and orderDate <= '2012-03-31 00:00:00.000'  
group by datepart(day,orderDate),orderdate,DATENAME(weekday,orderdate)
```

Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** after clarification.

Use case to change weekend days to friday. Derived table is employed to avoid the need to replicate the same expression everywhere orderdate is needed.

```
select DATENAME(weekday,orderdate_trimmed) Day,
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), orderdate_trimmed, 103) orderdate, 
       COUNT(orderdate_trimmed) Orders
from 
(
  select *, 
         order_date -
         case DATENAME(weekday,orderdate)
              when 'Saturday' then 1
              when 'Sunday' then 2
              else 0
          end
         orderdate_trimmed
    from Orders_tb
) a
where orderDate >= '2012-03-01 00:00:00.000'
  and orderDate <= '2012-03-31 00:00:00.000'
group by orderdate_trimmed
```

You might count matching days only by use of case statement:

```
select COUNT(orderdate) TotalOrders,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN DATENAME(weekday,orderdate) = 'Monday' then 1 end) Monday,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN DATENAME(weekday,orderdate) = 'Tuesday' then 1 end) Tuesday,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN DATENAME(weekday,orderdate) = 'Wednesday' then 1 end) Wednesday,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN DATENAME(weekday,orderdate) = 'Thursday' then 1 end) Thursday,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN DATENAME(weekday,orderdate) = 'Friday' 
                    OR DATENAME(weekday,orderdate) = 'Saturday' 
                    OR DATENAME(weekday,orderdate) = 'Sunday'
                  THEN 1 end) Friday
from Orders_tb
where orderDate >= '2012-03-01 00:00:00.000'  
and orderDate <= '2012-03-31 00:00:00.000'
```

A warning about dates: as a date can contain time portion it would be wiser to compare like this:

```
where orderDate >= '2012-03-01 00:00:00.000'  
and orderDate < '2012-04-01 00:00:00.000'
```

Comment: Thanks Nikola for your response, your query gave me what i was looking  for but I would want the data to be grouped by orderdate rather than summing all orders for a particular day of the week.Just as my original query,I need a group by clause in the query to achieve this.....Any Ideas?

Comment: @user851971 So what you actually need is to move weekend days into friday?

Comment: @user851971 Please check EDIT section of my answer.

Comment: Would it be more efficient to place the where conditions in the inner select?

Comment: @JamesJiao I suppose that it would not matter as optimizer produces the same execution plan, at least in my limited testing. It would not hurt though.